# Accessing GetValue() from wxWindow class

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Is there any way to access the GetValue() member of a GUI control under wxWidgets, if it is declared as a wxWindow rather than a wxCheckBox or wxRadioButton etc?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object declared as `WxWindow` is NOT a GUI control. A pointer declared as a `WxWindow*` might point to a `wxStaticText` object or a `wxCheckBox` object. You'd have to do a `dynamic_cast< >` to find out. Once you know it's a `wxCheckBox`, you can call `wxCheckBox::GetValue`. Similarly, if it's a `wxRadioButton`, you can call `wxRadioButton::GetValue`.

Note that per C++ rules, `wxCheckBox::GetValue` and `wxRadioButton::GetValue` are entirely unrelated. They just happen to have the same method name.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a derivative's function from a base pointer unless it's through a virtual function call, so no.

You can downcast though and get access to that function.